# Kernel Update on Live USB Harddrive 12.04LTS

Tags: 12.04, live-usb, portable

I need to create a portable working envrionment with ubuntu 12.04, so I install a live disk onto a 20GB FAT32 partition on my usb harddrive. I also created a ext4 partition on my usb disk labeling casper-rw (the capser-rw on FAT32 is deleted).
The problem is there when I try to update my system by using update-manager, after a kernel upgrade, I cannot boot into the system.
Do someone know how to upgrade the kernel? other software is updated correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that it is better not to update/upgrade persistent installs.
The kernel is located in the squashfs and can't be (easily) changed.

It is better to do a Full install if you need the latest kernel or updates.

A Full install is also faster to boot and more secure.

Comment: Yes, after experiment a lot of times, I'm convinced it cannot be done